# Displaying 50 copies of the number 0 in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I want to display 50 copies of number 0 in assembly.I have tried this ...

```
MOV CX,50
MOV AH,2
MOV DL,0

TOP:
INT 21H
LOOP TOP
```

Is there another solution available ? Then what is that ?

Comment: I prefer to write directly into the framebuffer for textmode = hex 0B800:0.

Comment: Your existing code won't work because you're writing a literal numeric `0`, which is not a displayable "character". The output routine is expecting ASCII representation because that's what makes the character displayable or printable. So you need to output `30` (`20h` in hex), not `0`. That is: `MOV DL, 30`. See the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com) for reference.

Comment: @lurker: well spotted, and likely the correct answer to the **Not A Question** – but still needs a few corrections. `30` is actually the hex value of the ASCII character `0`. `30(dec)` would be `1Eh` in hex, not `20h`. The decimal value of the character `0`, hex `30h`, is actually `48`.

Comment: @RadLexus haha right, I was in my pre-caffeine daze when I quoted those ASCII codes. Good catch. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not work!
Try this:

```
    mov cx, 00     ;Store 0 in cx
    loop:
    cmp cx, 50     ;Compare cx to 50
    je end         ;If we have printed 50 times, end the loop
    mov ah, 0x0e   ;Setting up interupt
    mov al, '0'    ;Character to print
    int 0x10       ;Print '0'
    inc cx         ;Add 1, to cx
    jmp loop       ;Do again or iterate
    end:
    .....          ;End (if you want to halt then use jmp $)
```

This code is for NASM and It is in 16 bit assembly.
If you want to print or move characters, in the case a '0', the you will have to enclose it with single quotes (' '). This will tell the assembler that it is a character and not a number. Once the assembler knows that it is a character, it will use ASCII the value for that number instead of taking the actual number.
The number can be "displayable" only when we use the ASCII value for that number.

Comment: You seem to love overly complicated loops. Your code uses 3 instructions and 1 label to many.